# Numpy Assigning with Indexing

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, slice

Why does the following code not produce the expected assignment?

```
A = np.array([[ 9.,  2.,  7.], [ 3.,  3.,  1.], [ 4.,  1.,  6.]])
L = np.zeros([3,3])
i = range(1,3)
L[i][:,[0]] = A[i][:,[0]] / A[0,0]
```

L continues to contain all zeros.  How do I produce what I expect to see (i.e. [[ 0.,  0.,  0.], [ .333,  0.,  0.], [ .444,  0.,  0.]])?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do direct indexing `L[i,0]=A[i,0]/A[0,0]`, otherwise you are working on a view rather than then a slice of the original `array`.